# segmentation fault (core dumped) when dynamically allocating a 2d array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am getting a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` when using a 2d array that has been dynamically allocated. My code is the followging:

```c
#define TMILKY 1e4 
#define TABLE_SIZE 10000

struct func_params{
    double *(pop)[3];
};
```

I want to allocate a 2d array of TABLE_SIZE rows and 3 columns .

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct func_params params;
    double t=0; 
    int i=0;

    params.pop[3] = malloc(sizeof(*params.pop[0]) * TABLE_SIZE);  
    if (params.pop == NULL) printf("population: allocation failed"); 
    while (t<TMILKY){  
        params.pop[0][i]=0;  
        params.pop[1][i]=2;
        params.population[2][i]=0;              
        printf("i %d t %e P %e B %e \n",i,t,params.population[0][i],params.population[1][i]);
        t = t+100;
        i++; 
    }
    
    free(params.population[3]); /* deallocate the buffer */

    return(0);
}
```

Could someone please help to spot my mistake...?

Comment: Your `struct func_params` doesn't have any member named `pop`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `sizeof(*params.pop[0]) * TABLE_SIZE` if the size is constant, then don't use malloc at all. And `1e4` is a double - just write `1000`.

Comment: sorry, this was because I was trying to make the code more simple.

Comment: @KamilCuk `1e4` in integer is `10000`, not `1000`.

Comment: `params.pop[3]` is out-of-range, so you must not assign anything there.

Comment: @KamilCuk Using `malloc()` for large array is a good strategy to avoid stack overflow even if the size is constant.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes actually I want to have an array of size 1e7 at least

Comment: @MikeCAT *`1e4` in integer is `10000`, not `1000`*  And that confusion is just ***another*** reason to not use a `double` value where an integer type is **necessary**.

Comment: *es actually I want to have an array of size 1e7 at least*  Why use `1e7`?  What happens when you run out of precision in your **floating point** value and it doesn't produce exactly the **integer** value you expect?

Comment: @AndrewHenle what do you mean...? The size corresponds to a number of physical objects

Comment: `long value = 1e14; printf( "1e14: %ld\n", value );`.  Who told you to use something like `1e4` when specifying the size of an array?  Doing that is so bad it's not even wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is a typo, I meant to use 10000

Comment: Then use `10000` in your code.  Not a floating point value such as `1e4`.  Floating point values such as `1e4` have limited precision.  You can put `1e7` in your code, expect to get `10000000` as the value, but actually get `9999932`.  The exact point this happens and the exact values you get don't matter - using a floating point value to define the size of an array is fundamentally ***wrong***.

Answer (score 1):

`params.pop[3]` is an out-of-range element. You must not read nor write anything there.

Instead of using that, you have to use `malloc()` and `free()` for each elements of `params.pop`.

Allocation:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    params.pop[j] = malloc(sizeof(*params.pop[j]) * TABLE_SIZE);  
}
```

Freeing:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    free(params.pop[j]);
}
```